# Microscopic mechanical energy conservation equation derivation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus, transport-phenomena

The transport phenomena book by Bird states that the mechanical energy equation can be derived by taking the dot product of the momentum conservation equation with the velocity vector **v**.

This is the momentum conservation equation:

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \rho\mathbf{v} = -[\nabla \cdot \rho\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}] -\nabla p - [\nabla \cdot\tau] + \rho \mathbf{g} $$

Where $\tau$ is the viscous stress (or momentum-flux) tensor and $\rho\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}$ is a dyadic product an represents the convective momentum-flux tensor.

The resulting mechanical energy equation is the following:

$$ \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{array}{llll}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{1}{2} \rho v^{2}\right)= & -\left(\nabla \cdot \frac{1}{2} \rho v^{2} \mathbf{v}\right) & -(\nabla \cdot p \mathbf{v}) & -p(-\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}) \\
\text { rate of } & \text { rate of addition } & \text { rate of work } & \text { rate of reversible } \\
\text { increase of } & \text { of kinetic energy } & \text { done by pressure } & \text { conversion of } \\
\text { kinetic energy } & \text { by convection } & \text { of surroundings } & \text { kinetic energy into } \\
\text { per unit volume } & \text { per unit volume } & \text { on the fluid } & \text { internal energy }
\end{array}\\
&\begin{array}{lll}
-(\nabla\cdot[\boldsymbol{\tau}\cdot\mathbf{v}]) & -(-\boldsymbol{\tau}: \nabla \mathbf{v}) & +\rho(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{g}) \\
\text { rate of work done } & \text { rate of } & \text { rate of work } \\
\text { by viscous forces } & \text { irreversible } & \text { by external force } \\
\text { on the fluid } & \text { conversion } & \text { on the fluid } \\
& \text { from kinetic to } & \\
& \text { internal energy } &
\end{array}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation} $$

I'm stumped on how to make the algebraic rearranging in order to go from one equation from another.